# NEO4j Cypher : How to set a value to the Max of 2 other values

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I need to retrospectively set a relationship property to the MAX of a value from the 2 nodes connected by it.

This sudo code is what im trying to do..

```
MATCH (a)-[r:Follows]->(b) SET r.prop = MAX(a.prop, b.prop)
```

But MAX doesn't work like that, its for finding the max from a collection.

Any ideas how to do this?

Comment: Does `MATCH ... WITH r, [a.prop, b.prop] AS vals UNWIND vals as val WITH r, MAX(val) as max_val SET r.prop = max_val` work? Collecting and unwinding the values this way puts them in the same 'result column' so you can use `MAX` on them. There's probably a nicer way though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is probably easiest with `CASE`.

```
MATCH (a)-[r:Follows]->(b)
SET r.prop = CASE WHEN a.prop > b.prop THEN a.prop ELSE b.prop END;
```

Comment: Are you sure? I'm getting `Error: Too many parameters for function 'max'`. I think `MAX` operates on a result column, like `COLLECT` and `COUNT`, so `MAX(a.prop)` above would give the highest `prop` value among the `a`:s matched in the query.

Comment: Woops, yeah, wasn't thinking. Edited.